# Firebase database now only displaying newly added annotations on map

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, annotations, mapkit

I have an app that allows people to put annotations on a map that get stored in a Firebase database, I have recently been trying to add a new feature to the app so to avoid messing about with my real database I created another app in firebase and used it for me to do my testing on. I deleted the GoogleService-Info.Plist and imported the one for the new test app but now when I delete the test GoogleService-Info.Plist and replace it with the one that works with my Live app none of my annotations show up on the map, but any I create from that point onwards will show up.

I've done a clean and build but still the same result.  All the data is still there in my original database as my AppStore version of the app works exactly as it should, I really don't know what could be wrong here, I'll let you see what my code is for retrieving the annotations, in case that helps you with your answer.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postboxesLoggedLabel: UILabel!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        displayAnnotations()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
        let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func displayAnnotations() {

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Postbox").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let monToFri = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Monday to Friday Collection Time"] as! String!
            let sat = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Saturday Collection Time"] as! String!
            let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Latitude"] as! String!
            let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["Longitude"] as! String!

            let lastCollection = "Mon - Fri: \(monToFri!)" + " Sat:  \(sat!)"



            self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
            self.annotation.title = "Last Collection:"
            self.annotation.subtitle = lastCollection

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)

            self.postboxesLoggedLabel.text = String(self.mapView.annotations.count)

        })

    }

    /*  func removeAnnotation(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

     if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

     self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
     print("Annotation Removed")

     }

     } */

    @IBAction func myLocation(_ sender: Any) {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    @IBAction func mapType(_ sender: Any) {

        switch ((sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = .standard
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = .satellite
        default: // or case 2
            mapView.mapType = .hybrid
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you look in the Firebase console to see if the apps are storing their data in different nodes within your app node.

Comment: Hi Jay, everything is saving to exactly where it's meant to, this has totally lost me, the only other thing i can think of that changed since my released App Store version is i updated my pods but my code hasn't changed ?